# Totals grouped by full weeks

Tags: sql-server

Ideally I would like the below to be more compact, that is, to remove the repetition of totaling by week for each week, with some form of iteration for the weeks back. It would be perfect if it could total via stored procedure, using "week's back" int, where it would total full weeks and then (wishlist item) total this current week's data up to now. Is this possible given the below? i.e. exec spGetTotalsWeeksBack 8, would look 8 weeks back, totaling only full weeks, (if the beginning date parameter is not a sunday, go to the next Sunday as the 1st week output).
Also I am having issues doing ISNULL, it is still not returning all clients even if 0. Any help is appreciated!

```
DECLARE @reportStartDate DATE = '2015-06-28' /*A Sunday, report start date*/

SELECT a.ClientName
    ,ISNULL(COUNT(CASE 
                WHEN DATEDIFF(week, @reportStartDate, RecordCreateDate) = 0
                    THEN 1
                END), 0) AS 'Week 1'
    ,ISNULL(COUNT(CASE 
                WHEN DATEDIFF(week, @reportStartDate, RecordCreateDate) = 1
                    THEN 1
                END), 0) AS 'Week 2'
    ,ISNULL(COUNT(CASE 
                WHEN DATEDIFF(week, @reportStartDate, RecordCreateDate) = 2
                    THEN 1
                END), 0) AS 'Week 3'
    ,ISNULL(COUNT(CASE 
                WHEN DATEDIFF(week, @reportStartDate, RecordCreateDate) = 3
                    THEN 1
                END), 0) AS 'Week 4'
FROM Client a WITH (NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN SecondaryClient b WITH (NOLOCK) ON b.MainClientID = a.ClientID
LEFT JOIN RecordLog c WITH (NOLOCK) ON c.ClientID = b.ClientID
    AND c.RecordCreateDate BETWEEN @reportStartDate /*Sunday, report start date*/
        AND DATEADD(week, 4, @reportStartDate) /* Saturday, report end date */
LEFT JOIN IncomingData d WITH (NOLOCK) ON d.DataID = c.DataID
    AND d.DataReceiveDate > @reportStartDate
    AND d.DataSourceID = 10
WHERE a.StatusID = 1
    AND a.ClientID IN (
        SELECT clientid
        FROM clientsettings
        WHERE active = 1
        )
GROUP BY a.ClientName
ORDER BY a.ClientName
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 problems here.

1. **"I am having issues doing ISNULL, it is still not returning all clients even if 0"**

You have this problem because you're filtering on LEFT JOIN-ed tables.

Consider rewrite query as UNION ALL of 2 queries each with INNER JOINS:

```
DECLARE @reportStartDate DATE = '2015-06-28' /*A Sunday, report start date*/

SELECT a.ClientName
    ,COUNT(CASE 
                WHEN DATEDIFF(week, @reportStartDate, RecordCreateDate) = 0
                    THEN 1
                END), 0) AS 'Week 1'
    ,COUNT(CASE 
                WHEN DATEDIFF(week, @reportStartDate, RecordCreateDate) = 1
                    THEN 1
                END), 0) AS 'Week 2'
    ,COUNT(CASE 
                WHEN DATEDIFF(week, @reportStartDate, RecordCreateDate) = 2
                    THEN 1
                END), 0) AS 'Week 3'
    ,COUNT(CASE 
                WHEN DATEDIFF(week, @reportStartDate, RecordCreateDate) = 3
                    THEN 1
                END), 0) AS 'Week 4'
FROM Client a WITH (NOLOCK)
JOIN SecondaryClient b WITH (NOLOCK) ON b.MainClientID = a.ClientID
JOIN RecordLog c WITH (NOLOCK) ON c.ClientID = b.ClientID
    AND c.RecordCreateDate BETWEEN @reportStartDate /*Sunday, report start date*/
        AND DATEADD(week, 4, @reportStartDate) /* Saturday, report end date */
JOIN IncomingData d WITH (NOLOCK) ON d.DataID = c.DataID
    AND d.DataReceiveDate > @reportStartDate
    AND d.DataSourceID = 10
WHERE a.StatusID = 1
    AND a.ClientID IN (
        SELECT clientid
        FROM clientsettings
        WHERE active = 1
        )
GROUP BY a.ClientName
UNION ALL -- non existent values
SELECT DISTINCT a.client, Week1=0, Week2=0,Week3=0, Week4=0
FROM Client a WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM 
    SecondaryClient b WITH (NOLOCK) ON b.MainClientID = a.ClientID
    JOIN RecordLog c WITH (NOLOCK) ON c.ClientID = b.ClientID
        AND c.RecordCreateDate BETWEEN @reportStartDate /*Sunday, report start date*/
            AND DATEADD(week, 4, @reportStartDate) /* Saturday, report end date */
    JOIN IncomingData d WITH (NOLOCK) ON d.DataID = c.DataID
        AND d.DataReceiveDate > @reportStartDate
        AND d.DataSourceID = 10
    WHERE a.StatusID = 1
        AND a.ClientID IN (
            SELECT clientid
            FROM clientsettings
            WHERE active = 1
            )
)
```

2. **"It would be perfect if it could total via stored procedure, using "week's back" int, where it would total full weeks and then (wishlist item) total this current week's data up to now. Is this possible given the below? i.e. exec spGetTotalsWeeksBack 8, would look 8 weeks back, totaling only full weeks"**

I suppose you can do something like `GROUP BY (DATEDIFF(week, @reportStartDate, RecordCreateDate` and then PIVOT-ing result.

Although, I afraid that you can't avoid dynamic sql for columns Week0-WeekN.